# change for $1 using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics

Using only pennies and dimes, how many ways can you make change for $1 using generating functions.

I came up with the equation $(1+x^2+x^3+\ldots)(1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\ldots)$

which simplifies to $\frac{1}{1-x^1}\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}$.

I assume I need to find the coefficient at $x^{100}$ because it's $100$ cents, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read it off via: $x^{10}x^{90}+x^{20}x^{80}+\ldots$. So it amounts to figuring out how many terms you have.

Comment: it's the number of combined terms up through  (x^100)(x^0)?

Comment: Precisely. If you want a small example, work it out explicitly for making 20c instead of $1.

Comment: if it was 20 cents, there would be three ways: 10 pennies and 1 dime, 20 pennies and 0 dimes, and 0 pennies, 2 dimes. So, for $1, it would be 11 ways